# CDI RequestScope giving multiple object on a request

Tags: java, cdi

I have an application in which we have a bean as

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserSession extends SessionMessage {

}
```

Then we have a `WebFilter` in which the above bean in injected. The filter populates all the properties on this `userSession` object.

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject
    private UserSession userSession;
    .....
    public void doFilter(....){
        .....
        someService.populateSession(userSession);
        chain.doFilter(req, res)
    }

}
```

and then on the

```
@Path("/token")
public class TokenService {
    @Inject
    private UserSession userSession;
    .....
}
```

I am expecting the same object that is injected in the `SessionFilter` is injected in the `TokenService`. However, I am getting different object in `TokenService` than one injected in `SessionFilter`.

I am not able to figure out why same object is not injected when I have defined it to be RequestScope. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you clarify what implementations you are using?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with *the same object*?
If you call the getter-methods, are the things set in the filter still there in *TokenService*?

The Beans injected in *SessionFilter* and *TokenService* are cdi-proxy-objects hiding the actual instance per request.
For further details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681981/why-cdi-beans-dont-support-final-methods)

Comment: The properties that are set in filter are not available in TokenService. If I log the userSession object in filter and token, I get following 

Sep 02, 2014 3:34:40 PM SessionFilter doFilter
INFO: UserSession: UserSession@3fcfbc65
Sep 02, 2014 3:34:40 PM TokenService createToken
INFO: UserSession: UserSession@5f59ab9d

From this, I realized I am getting a seperate object, and not the one that is injected in filter.

Comment: It's like i said: The beans injected are proxies hiding the real instance (per request). Use setter- and getter-methods to access properties and it should work as expected.

Comment: I understand that these are proxy objects. I am using getter method to get the properties of userSession. However, the properties are not set when I try to access it in TokenService. I can see the properties set in Filter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same Problem. I am Using Java EE 7 with wildfly 8.1.

My current solution is to use

```
HttpServletRequest context = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
```

this could be used inside your *UserSession* to populate the Session via Http-Header

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserSession extends SessionMessage {

    public Session getSession() {

        HttpServletRequest context = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
        Session session = someService.populateSession(context);
        return session;
    }

}
```