# Spring annotation @Validated not working in kotlin class, same java code works

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, kotlin

I'm have kotlin get request.
Validation are not working, Possible to specify day of week more or less validate limits

```
@RestController
@Validated
open class GetCrab {
    @GetMapping("/v1/get")
open fun getNameOfDayByNumber(@RequestParam dayOfWeek: @Min(1) @Max(7) Int?): String {
        return "ok"
    }
}
```

In the same java code validation works

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class GetCrab {

    @GetMapping("/v1/get")
    public String getNameOfDayByNumber(@RequestParam @Min(1) @Max(7) Integer dayOfWeek) {

        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Java code when validation works: request:

http://localhost:12722/v1/get?dayOfWeek=100

Response ->

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "details": "getNameOfDayByNumber.dayOfWeek: must be less than or equal to 7"
    }
]
```

}

Kotlin code, request http://localhost:12722/v1/get?dayOfWeek=100

Response:

```
ok
```

Comment: You should probably add some details about how you are calling your code and errors/responses you get back for the non working code.

Comment: Alright so you should probably say how this code is being served, like I have this running in Tomcat and when I do a GET request like the following my Java code works fine but when I do the request to the Kotlin code I get a response that looks like X. Put that somewhere in your question not in the comments here.

Comment: I'm add example request and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `open` modifier for methods too.

E.g. please try code:

```
@RestController
@Validated
open class GetCrab {
    @GetMapping("/v1/get")
    open fun getNameOfDayByNumber(@RequestParam dayOfWeek: @Min(1) @Max(7) Int?): String {
        return "ok"
    }
}
```

Both class and method should be `open` (in Java terms - both of them shouldn't be final), [because of Spring proxy logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681981/why-cdi-beans-dont-support-final-methods). From linked article: Spring tries to inherit your class, because sometimes you can request exact your class from @Autowired parameter.

By default all classes and methods [are not final in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html). However Kotlin classes/methods [are final by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance), so you need to put `open` keyword before them to have ability to override.